# How read cookies by jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Hi I have this code that load a page from index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function jsonCallback(json){
  console.log(json);
  alert(document.cookie.json)
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
</script>
```

I want get cookies, so in https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-2.json I've executed in Console: `document.cookie='test=123'` and return undefined. Why? How can I fix it?

Here's what that URL returns:

```
jsonCallback(
  {
    "sites":
    [
      {
        "siteName": "SitePoint",
        "domainName": "https://www.sitepoint.com",
        "description": "SitePoint is a hub for web developers to share their passion for building incredible Internet things."
      },
      {
        "siteName": "A List Apart",
        "domainName": "http://alistapart.com/",
        "description": "A List Apart explores the design, development, and meaning of web content, with a special focus on web standards and best practices."
      },
      {
        "siteName": "Smashing Magazine",
        "domainName": "https://www.smashingmagazine.com/",
        "description": "Smashing Magazine delivers useful and innovative information to Web designers and developers."
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

Comment: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) != [JSON](http://json.org) Both ends of your example do in fact conform to JSONP, but the `.json` on the URL gives the impression it's going to return JSON instead.

Comment: `alert(document.cookie.json)`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript code in your page to read cookies for other origins. If you have `http://example.com/foo.html` and in it you load a script (which is what you're doing with JSONP) from `http://api.com/`, any cookies returned with the response from `http://api.com/` are associated with `http://api.com/`. You can't read them with JavaScript code in `http://example.com/foo.html`.

Comment: No way to get it?

Comment: @Snoopy: If there were, it would be a major, major, major security breach in the browser.